# "The Events Calendar" Issues in WP 3.2

Tags: plugins, jquery, the-events-calendar

After updating to Wordpress 3.2, the show/hide functionality of the event authoring area on "The Events Calendar" is backwards - when the "All Day Event?" checkbox is checked, the time boxes appear. When it is unchecked, the time boxes disappear. This is *opposite* behavior of what should happen.

I suspect it's a Jquery issue. Has anyone else discovered this issue?

[image: All day event unchecked]
[image: All day event checked]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer: The new version of Wordpress using version 1.6 of JQuery. In the file events-meta-box.php, change anywhere where it says:

```
.attr('checked') == true
```

to:

```
.prop("checked", true)
```

There should be three locations where you fix it.

Comment: This fix seems to cause the day field to display on the post edit page 4 times. The correct date seems to be included in the post itself. This seems to be a problem (with the fix included) that only manifests on the edit page of the post. Will continue to test the validity of the date handling.

Comment: don't type it as a answer.type it in comment section.

Comment: Huh? This is the answer! I'll re-word to indicate this is the answer.